# Как изменить поведение JsonDecoder

Tags: python, json

у меня в json строке есть `datetime.datetime`. Мне требуется, чтобы `JsonDecoder` парсил `datetime.datetime`, как объект. Я уже нашёл, как это можно сделать:

```
import ast
import datetime
from operator import attrgetter

value_from_db = "datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 00, 00)"

expr, = ast.parse(value_from_db).body
dt_value = datetime.datetime(*map(attrgetter('n'), expr.value.args))

print(dt_value)
```

Теперь мне нужно, чтобы при использование `json.loads`, это делалось автоматически.
Пример того, как должно работать:

```
json_string = '{"last_updated": {"$gte": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 19, 0, 0)}}'
dct = json.loads(json_string)
print(dct) # -> {"last_updated": {"$gte": datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 19, 0, 0)}}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/json/custom-deserialization/

Comment: в таком виде - это не валидный json. только  предварительная обработка в тексте. Но если взять в кавычки, то можно сделать автоматически через object_hook

Comment: @splash58 А вот можете подсказать, object_hook выполняется до десериализации, или уже после? И если делать через него, то можете пожалуйста по подробнее рассказать, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object_hook выполняется после десериализации, поэтому вам все равно нужен валидный json. Но вы можете передать datetime объект в виде строки и сделать следующим образом:

```
import json
import datetime

def objHook(dst):
    for k,v in dst.items():
        if isinstance(v, str) and v.startswith('datetime.datetime'):
            args = v.replace('datetime.datetime(', '').replace(')','').replace(' ', '').split(',')
            args = map(int, args)
            dst[k] = datetime.datetime(*args)
    return dst

json_string = '{"last_updated": {"$gte": "datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 19, 0, 0)"}}'
dct = json.loads(json_string, object_hook=objHook)
print(dct)  #  {'last_updated': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 19, 0, 0)}}
```